# Swift: How to check object is Array or String class?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, class, swift

I'm learning the Swift language. I have a problem with check object is String or Array class:

---

**Objective-c**

```
NSObject *values = [keywords valueForKey:index];
if ([values isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    //...
}
else if([values isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    //...
}
```

---

**Swift:** I can't use *isKindOfClass* to check String or Array class

Answer (score 5):

Given a value extracted from a dictionary:

```
var value: AnyObject? = keywords[index]
```

You can check its type using the `is` operator:

```
if value is NSString { 
    println("It's a string")
} else if values is NSArray {
    println("It's an NSArray")
}
```

or using a `switch` statement:

```
switch (value) {
case let value as NSString:
    println("It's an NSString")
case let value as NSArray: 
    println("It's an NSArray")
default:
    println("None of the above")
}
```